# Get radio button choice value in Ajax Behavior

Tags: java, radio-button, wicket

How can I get radio button choice "live" in wicket? I mean if I've a radio button with two choices A and B and I want to add an ajax behavior (on change, on update, whatever works) to the button so that if I chose A it happens something in the page, if I chose B happens something else. Can You help me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just add an [`AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/7.x/org/apache/wicket/ajax/form/AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior.html) to the `RadioChoice`:

```
RadioChoice radioChoice = new RadioChoice("myRadio", choiceList);
radioChoice.add( new AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") { 
    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        // Ajax actions here
        System.out.println("The selected value is " + getComponent().getDefaultModelObjectAsString()));
    }
}  );
form.add(radioChoice);
```

The Model of the `RadioChoice` will already be updated when executing `onUpdate`. Remember to add to `target` all components that are to be refreshed via AJAX (and of course to set `setOutputMarkupId(true)` to them).

There's an online example with source code of what you're looking for [here](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples-6.0.x/compref/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.compref.RadioChoicePage). The relevant source code file is [this one](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples-6.0.x/compref/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.source.SourcesPage?3&SourcesPage_class=org.apache.wicket.examples.compref.RadioChoicePage&source=RadioChoicePage.java).